# Django: form works in index but not in a particular page

Tags: django

I'm having multiple forms around my website.

However, a have a particular form that is working in the home page (index.html), but when coping this particular form in a section of my site it doesn't work anymore (on this section, if I return to home everything works as expected).

What am I missing?

**Views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import Treasure, TamaniosCantidades
from .forms import TreasureForm, TamaniosCantidadesForm, LoginForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout


# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    treasures = Treasure.objects.all()
    form = TreasureForm()
    tamanioscantidades_form = TamaniosCantidadesForm()
    return render(request, 'main_app/index.html', {'treasures': treasures,
                                                   'form': form,
                                                   'tamanioscantidades_form': tamanioscantidades_form})


def productos(request):
    treasures = Treasure.objects.all()
    form = TreasureForm()
    return render(request, 'main_app/productos.html', {'treasures': treasures,
                                                       'form': form})


def die_cut(request):
    tamanioscantidades_form = TamaniosCantidadesForm()
    return render(request, 'main_app/die-cut-stickers.html', {'tamanioscantidades_form': tamanioscantidades_form})


def post_tamanioscantidades(request):
    form = TamaniosCantidadesForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        tamanioscantidades = TamaniosCantidades(tamanios=form.cleaned_data['tamanios'],
                            cantidades=form.cleaned_data['cantidades'])
        # tamanioscantidades = tamanioscantidades_form.save(commit = False)
        # tamanioscantidades.usuario = request.user
        tamanioscantidades.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')


def post_treasure(request):
    form = TreasureForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        treasure = Treasure(name=form.cleaned_data['name'],
                            value=form.cleaned_data['value'])

        treasure.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

**urls.py**:

```
app_name = 'main_app'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('productos/', views.productos),
    path('productos/die-cut-stickers', views.die_cut, name='die-cut-stickers'),
    path('post_url/', views.post_treasure, name='post_treasure'),
    path('post_url_tamanioscantidades/', views.post_tamanioscantidades, name='post_tamanioscantidades'),
]
```

*html**:

```
<div class="col-md-6 border border-primary rounded border-3">

                    <div class="m-5">

                        <div class="row">
                            <form action="post_url_tamanioscantidades/" method="post">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                {{ tamanioscantidades_form.as_p }}
                                <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                            </form>

                    </div>


                </div>
```

As I said, this form works in home, but when coping the same code in a section of my site the submit button does not save the form in database.

It returns:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/productos/post_url_tamanioscantidades/
Using the URLconf defined in gallito.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
productos/
productos/die-cut-stickers [name='die-cut-stickers']
post_url/ [name='post_treasure']
post_url_tamanioscantidades/ [name='post_tamanioscantidades']
accounts/
The current path, productos/post_url_tamanioscantidades/, didn't match any of these.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the form is being submitted to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/productos/post_url_tamanioscantidades/` which does not exist instead you want it to submit at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/post_url_tamanioscantidades/`

So in your form html start the form action with `/`

```
<form action="/post_url_tamanioscantidades/" method="post">
```

Comment: ty. I think I can use alse the name of the URLPATTERN? Any hint on that?

Comment: you can with  `<form action="{% url 'post_tamanioscantidades' %}" method="post">`